Proving a Multiplication Map is Unbounded
I am trying to verify something quite basic, but for whatever reason is proving to be troublesome to come up with.
Let $H = \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$, and $K := K(H)$.  Give an example of a sequence $(x_n)_n \subset K \otimes K$ such that $x_n \longrightarrow 0$ in norm, but $\lVert m(x_n) \rVert \longrightarrow \infty$ where $m: K \odot K \longrightarrow K$ is given by $m(T \otimes S) = TS$.
First of all, I know that $x_n \neq T_n \otimes S_n$ since then $\lVert m(x_n) \rVert = \lVert T_nS_n \rVert \leq \lVert T_n \rVert \lVert S_n \rVert = \lVert T_n \otimes S_n \rVert \longrightarrow 0$.  Moreover If $x_n = \sum_{k=1}^n T_n \otimes S_n$, then the series can't be absolutely summable, otherwise we get: $$\lVert m(x_n) \rVert \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \lVert T_n \otimes S_n \rVert < \infty.$$  This leads me to want to consider terms that aren't quite elementary tensors, something like $x_n = T_n \otimes S_n + R_n \otimes V_n$.  However, I'm kind of lost for ideas on what $T_n,S_n,R_n,V_n$ would need to be to get this to work.  $x_n$ needs to be compact since $x_n \in K \odot K \subset K(H \otimes H)$ so ideally the operators $T_n,S_n,R_n,V_n$ are finite rank.
If someone could give me a hint or point me in the right direction that'd be great.
